# Understanding the ss() and tf2ss() functions and their differences

Tags: matlab, state-space, transfer-function, control-theory

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71118265/4999991), I am trying to comprehend the functionality of MATLAB's [`ss()`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/ss.html#mw_f9c0739d-42f0-4a54-b73f-3f79fdcce563) and [`tf2ss()`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tf2ss.html#mw_00866a1a-957f-4a9a-9381-b6adbe331a90) functions and their differences. Consider the code below:

```matlab
Kf = 0.2;   
J = 0.02; 

h2 = tf(1, [J Kf]);

dcm1 = ss(h2);
dcm2 = tf2ss(h2.Numerator{1}, h2.Denominator{1});
```

partially copied from [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/dc-motor-control.html). Now I expect the `dcm1` and `dcm2` to be identical but here is what I get:

```
>> dcm1

dcm1 =
 
  A = 
        x1
   x1  -10
 
  B = 
       u1
   x1   8
 
  C = 
         x1
   y1  6.25
 
  D = 
       u1
   y1   0
 
Continuous-time state-space model.

>> dcm2

dcm2 =

   -10
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me understand why am I getting two different results? how I can have identical results using the `tf2ss()` function? In other words, I want to create a `dcm2` which is identical to `dcm1` but using the `tf2ss()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ss` returns a state-space `system`, similar to `tf` they both return continuous systems in `ss` and `tf` representation respectively.

`ss2tf` returns the A, B, C, D matrices which are the result of converting the transfer function `tf` into its state-space representation.

There's one caveat though, the state-space representation of a transfer function is not unique. It seems like `Matlab` uses two different algorithms for `ss` and `tf2ss`. You can verify that both systems return the same transfer function:

```
Kf = 0.2;   
J = 0.02; 

h2 = tf(1, [J Kf]);

dcm1 = ss(h2);
[A, B, C, D] = tf2ss(h2.Numerator{1}, h2.Denominator{1});
```

dcm1 =

```
  A = 
        x1
   x1  -10
 
  B = 
       u1
   x1   8
 
  C = 
         x1
   y1  6.25
 
  D = 
       u1
   y1   0
```

[A, B, C, D]

```
A = -10
B = 1
C = 50
D = 0
```

Now let's compare transfer functions:

```
[b, a] = ss2tf(A, B, C, D)
% yields
b = [0 50]
a = [1 10]

[b, a] = ss2tf(dcm1.a, dcm1.b, dcm1.c, dcm1.d)
% yields
b = [0 50]
a = [1 10]
```

Comment: have you tried the suggested line above? The result is not identical! 

Comment: @FoadS.Farimani the matrices will contain the same values, but the result won't be wrapped in a continuous time system representation. If you try printing `dcm1.a` and `A` to the console you should see `-10`.

Comment: It appears that the `ss()` function, returns `ss` class, but the `tf2ss()` returns `double`.

Comment: @FoadS.Farimani yep that is correct.

Comment: nope, `dcm1 --> A = -10 , B = 8, C = 6.25, D = 0` but `dcm2 --> -10     1    50     0`

Comment: @FoadS.Farimani I've updated my answer. The reason `ss` and `tf2ss` are returning different results is because the state-space representation of a transfer function is not unique, and it seems like each method use a different algorithm.

Comment: This is strange! Thanks for the elaboration. I will do more research and come back.

Comment: Thanks for your kind support. [This follow-up Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71213364/4999991) might also be interesting for you.

Comment: @FoadS.Farimani thanks for sharing the info. These were a good set of questions!