# How to convert a state-space model to transfer function?

Tags: matlab, state-space, transfer-function, control-theory

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71166489/4999991), I am trying to convert the state-space model from [this tutorial](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/dc-motor-control.html) back into its transfer-function form. I have tried the

```matlab
R = 2.0;                % Ohms
L = 0.5;                % Henrys
Km = 0.1;               % torque constant
Kb = 0.1;               % back emf constant
Kf = 0.2;               % Nms
J = 0.02;               % kg.m^2/s^2
Td = 1;                 % models load disturbances

h1 = tf(Km, [L R]);            % armature
h2 = tf(1, [J Kf]);            % eqn of motion
dcm = ss(h2) * [h1 , Td];      % w = h2 * (h1 * Va + Td)

[b, a] = ss2tf(dcm.A, dcm.B, dcm.C, dcm.D);
dcm_tf = tf(b, a);
```

However, I get the error message:

> IU must be specified for systems with more than one input.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this comment on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/matlab/comments/1xb6mt/comment/cf9skf0/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), given the above system is [Multiple-Input-Multiple-Output (MIMO)](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/introduction-to-mimo-systems.html), we need to specify the [input index `ni`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ss2tf.html#buh3rcg-ni) from the `ss2tf()`function. In this case the

```
[b, a] = ss2tf(dcm.A, dcm.B, dcm.C, dcm.D, 1);
```

returns the `w / Va` transfer function and the

```
[b, a] = ss2tf(dcm.A, dcm.B, dcm.C, dcm.D, 2);
```

returns the `w / Td` one.

Alternatively, one could simply use the `tf(dcm)` to convert the state-space model directly to transfer functions of both inputs.